# Can't download .xls file using a href download attribute

Tags: html, download, attributes, href

I'm trying to download Tabel1.xls file using a a href download attribute when pressing the "Descarcare tabel" button, while the path is made from the current origin into a folder called "Documente Excel". The path is good and working, when I tested it in Inspect Element, but it doesn't work when I press the button. Is there something wrong?

[Here's the whole thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj5Dg.png)

Comment: Did you check if the path is correct and does open the file when manually opening the path?

Comment: Yes, the file opens